# How to coalesce a list in dataframe in spark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, coalesce

I have a code like this

```
columns = ("language","users_count","status")
data = (("Java",None,"1"), ("Python", "100000","2"), ("Scala", "3000","3"))
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF(columns)
df.withColumn('concat', regexp_replace(concat( coalesce(*columns)), " ", "")).show()
```

the result is:

```
+--------+-----------+------+------+
|language|users_count|status|concat|
+--------+-----------+------+------+
|    Java|       null|     1|  Java|
|  Python|     100000|     2|Python|
|   Scala|       3000|     3| Scala|
+--------+-----------+------+------+
```

If I want the `concat` column is `Java1` I need to code:

````
df.withColumn('concat', regexp_replace(concat(
coalesce('language',lit('')),
coalesce('users_count', lit('')),
coalesce('status', lit('')) ), " ", "")).show()```
````

Which looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+------+-------------+
|language|users_count|status|       concat|
+--------+-----------+------+-------------+
|    Java|       null|     1|        Java1|
|  Python|     100000|     2|Python1000002|
|   Scala|       3000|     3|   Scala30003|
+--------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

Can anyone help me to fix the  `coalesce(*columns)` so that I don't need to write all the coalesce for each columns in `columns`? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat_ws`

```
>>> df.show()
+--------+-----------+------+
|language|users_count|status|
+--------+-----------+------+
|    Java|       null|     1|
|  Python|     100000|     2|
|   Scala|       3000|     3|
+--------+-----------+------+

>>> df.withColumn('concat', concat_ws("",*columns)).show()
+--------+-----------+------+-------------+
|language|users_count|status|       concat|
+--------+-----------+------+-------------+
|    Java|       null|     1|        Java1|
|  Python|     100000|     2|Python1000002|
|   Scala|       3000|     3|   Scala30003|
+--------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to write it more convenient in case of list columns can change.

Comment: @VõHoàngAnh : Updated